# Передать значения одного input file в другой input file

Tags: jquery

```
<input type="file" name="images[]" id="img" class="nameForm" multiple="true" accept="image/*,image/jpeg">
<iframe name="uploadImg" src="#" id="frameImg"></iframe>
```

Содержимое ифрейма:

```
<input type="file" name="images[]" id="imgUpl" class="nameForm" multiple="true" accept="image/*,image/jpeg">
```

Как пытаюсь засунуть туда данные:

```
var img = document.getElementById('img').value;

$('#imgUpl').attr('value', img.val);
alert(img.val);
```

При алерте выдает андефаенд.

Как можно реализовать, чтобы значения одного инпут файла можно было передать в другой инпут файл? Или же там только чтение?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

По соображениям безопасности атрибут value у input file работает только в режиме чтения.

Потом `undefined` вылетает из-за того, что вы откуда-то берете у стринговой записи свойство `val`.

Должно быть так:

```
var img = document.getElementById('img').value;

$('#imgUpl').attr('value', img);
alert(img);
```

И потом с iframe общаемся так:

```
var iframeDoc = iframe.contentWindow.document;
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает. А есть ли возможность засунуть эти значения в #imgUpl? То, что у меня, не работает.

Comment: @rimlin вам же говорят, value у input file работает только на чтение :-)